# Recuperar código de classe Java no NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, backup

Meu computador sofreu um desligamento forçado por conta de um pique de luz e quando voltei a abrir meu projeto no NetBeans (8.2) uma das classes estava vazia, tem alguma forma de recuperar tal código?

Comment: Tente isto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950754/netbeans-revert-project-changes-from-a-special-date

Comment: O manual do Local history do netbeans tambem pode ajudar a fazer essa reversao: https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/LocalHistory/

Comment: O histórico dele está vazio, como se ele nunca tivesse sido alterado

Comment: Se você esqueceu de salvar antes do pique de luz, sinto muito, tenho uma triste noticia para você...

Comment: Eu havia salvado poucos minutos antes, tenho mania de salvar a todo momento, além disso sumiu todo o código da classe, não só o que eu modifiquei hoje

Comment: @WilliamAssunção Abre a classe por um editor de texto normal e vê o conteúdo. Se o arquivo tiver vazio, vai ter que usar algum software pra recuperar.

Comment: Fez a verificação do windows no disco? Geralmente quando ocorre um desligamento abrupto, logo na proxima inicialização, o windows pergunta se quer checar o disco, demora, mas ao menos você sabe se algum setor danificou, e pode ser isso a causa da corrupção de alguns arquivos.

Comment: Está vazio, e não pediu nenhuma verificação, inicializou normalmente